# how to create trigger so that one can't insert date earlier than 2017 and later than 2019

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, database-trigger

```
Create or replace Trigger in_vehicle
Before Insert of PURCHASE_DATE On Vehicle 
for each row
Begin
IF(:new.PURCHASE_DATE < '12/31/2016')
THEN
raise_application_error(20001, 'the Hire date must be between 2017 and 2020');
end if 
if(:new.PURCHASE_DATE > '12/31/2016') and  (:new.PURCHASE_DATE > '01/01/2020')
then raise_application_error(20001, 'the Hire date must be between 2017 and 2020');
end if;
end;
```

ORA-04073: column list not valid for this trigger type

Comment: You compare `DATE` values with strings, don't do that. Use DATE literals `DATE '2016-12-31'` or [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) function `TO_DATE('12/31/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`.

Answer (score 2):

First, no need to specify the column name in the trigger declaration, just the table name goes here

```
Before insert on table_name
```

Second, the Ifs seem to be redundant to me, I'll just say "less than or greater than".

An the third, the exception numbers are always (as far I as know) negative. "-20001" in your case.
Here is the example of the trigger you probably need

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger in_vehicle
Before Insert On qq
for each row
Begin
  IF(:new.PURCHASE_DATE < to_date('12/31/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) or (:new.PURCHASE_DATE > to_date('01/01/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'the Hire date must be between 2017 and 2020');
  end if;
end;
```

On the other hand, such a limitation could be implemented in much simplier manner by using the check constraint on the table. Like this

```
alter table your_table add constraint purchase_date_2017_2019 check (purchase_date between to_date('01.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date('31.12.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

Disadvantage here is that exception will look like "Constraint purchase_date_2017_2019 violated". Not self explanatory and needs and extra handling to sent a clear message to the user

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Before (and After) Insert triggers don't take a column list (like Before and After Update triggers do), since you always insert an entire row, regardless if any of columns in it are `null`.

Just remove the `of` clause and you should be fine:

```
Create or replace Trigger in_vehicle
Before Insert On Vehicle -- Of clause removed
for each row
-- etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

This trigger worked. :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger in_vehicle
Before Insert On qq
for each row
Begin
  IF(:new.PURCHASE_DATE < to_date('12/31/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) or (:new.PURCHASE_DATE > to_date('01/01/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'the Hire date must be between 2017 and 2020');
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see any reason about why you are using `trigger` for date validation? If you are getting date value from `oracle-apex` `page-item` (pardon but you have added `oracle-apex` as your `tag`) then you can simply create a `date field/item` and simply provide `min-date` and `max-date` values. It will restrict users to select a date in a given date-time period. You can create a `validation` in `oracle-apex` too.

Another thing is, your code has many mistakes like you were comparing date field with a string try using `to_date()`. Error function must throw a negative number like `-20001`.